# TypeError: must be convertible to a buffer, not ResultSet

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scraperwiki

I am trying to convert a PDF into a text file using [scraperwiki](https://scraperwiki.com/) and [bs4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). I am getting a `TypeError`. I am very new at Python and would really appreciate a little assistance.

Error occurs here:

```
File "scraper_wiki_download.py", line 53, in write_file
f.write(soup)
```

This is my code:

```
# Get content, regardless of whether an HTML, XML or PDF file
def send_Request(url):        
    response = http.urlopen('GET', url, preload_content=False)
    return response

# Use this to get PDF, covert to XML
def process_PDF(fileLocation):
    pdfToProcess = send_Request(fileLocation)
    pdfToObject = scraperwiki.pdftoxml(pdfToProcess.read())
    return pdfToObject

# returns a navigatibale tree, which you can iterate through
def parse_HTML_tree(contentToParse):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contentToParse, 'lxml')
    return soup

pdf = process_PDF('http://www.sfbos.org/Modules/ShowDocument.aspx?documentid=54790')
pdfToSoup = parse_HTML_tree(pdf)
soupToArray = pdfToSoup.findAll('text')

def write_file(soup_array):
    with open('test.txt', "wb") as f:
        f.write(soup_array)

write_file(soupToArray)
```

Comment: It could help to know which line throws the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never used scraperwiki till now but this gets the text:

```
import scraperwiki
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

pdf_xml = scraperwiki.pdftoxml(requests.get('http://www.sfbos.org/Modules/ShowDocument.aspx?documentid=54790').content)
print(BeautifulSoup(pdf_xml, "lxml").find_all("text"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess `soupToArray = pdfToSoup.findAll('text')` returns some kind of list, but `f.write()` works only on string, so you have to iterate on it and transform each element to a string in some way. Print soupToArray to see exactly what it looks like.

Comment: It looks like you are right. Unfortunately, I am getting an empty list. It doesn't seem like pdfToSoup is doing its job.